# como usar encode con una funcion href en javascript

Tags: php, javascript

me gustaria que me explicaran y si  (ya que no soy experto en programacion )es que se puede lo siguiente  uso la funcion

```js
function mostrarnoticia (id){
    window.location.href='noticiacompleta.php?noticias='+id;
}
```

para que me abra otra ventana y me muestre la info ... como en la url me saldra

noticiacompleta.php?noticia=3

como usar esa funcion con un **encode**

```js
function mostrarnoticia (id){
    window.location.href='noticiacompleta.php?noticias='+id;
    
    }
    
    encode();
```

no se si sea posible y si lo es como seria para que me encripte la url ?

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con un encode? ¿Quieres encriptar el 3?

Comment: si quiero encriptarlo porq no quiero q salga el id

Answer (score 0):

No recomendaría encriptar el id, es mejor usar un slug:

- Agrega un campo slug a tu tabla noticias en la base de datos.
- Cada vez que se guarde una noticia preocúpate de guardar el slug con el formato: titulo-de-la-noticia.
- Es muy importante que los slugs no se repitan, verifica eso antes de guardarlo.
- En lugar de mandar el id, manda el slug para buscar la noticia: noticiacompleta.php?noticias=titulo-de-la-noticia.

Para encriptar el id, tendrás que usar una función en PHP al momento de mostrar (function encriptar) y al momento de recibir el GET (function desencriptar), es un tedio que realmente no te entrega mucha seguridad (mejor usar autenticación si son datos sensibles). Es preferible la alternativa del slug.

Dime si tienes alguna duda.

Comment: en la funcion en vz de mandar la palabra id  .. escripbiria slug ?

Comment: Claro, en el fondo usarás el slug como id, en tu función en Javascript podría ser algo como function mostrarnoticia (slug). Y en tu consulta en la base de datos harías algo como esto: SELECT * FROM noticias WHERE slug = 'titulo-de-la-noticia';

Comment: en la funcion hice lo siguiente

Comment: function mostrarnoticia (slug){
    window.location.href='noticiacompleta.php?noticias='+slug;
    
    }

Comment: Eso está bien, pero agregaste el campo en la base de datos? Y estás guardando las noticias con el slug?

Comment: no no de verdad no entiendo